# Video analysis with Microsoft Vision API using python

Tags: python, api, computer-vision

A C# Example for using Micorosft Cognitive Vision API on Real time videos can be found here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/vision-api-how-to-topics/howtoanalyzevideo_vision

I cannot find something similar for Python.
How would I go about do that in Python?